# C# String gone from struct

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, string, dictionary

Ok.. I have a really awkward problem that I believe is related with how C# handles value types vs reference types but I'm just not sure what exactly the bug is.

```
public partial class LogicSimulationViewerForm : Form
    {

    private Dictionary<string, PointStruct> pointValues;


private void SearchPoint(string code)
    {
        ReadDefaultPointValuesResponse result = ddcdao.ReadDefaultPoint(points);
        pointValues = new Dictionary<string, PointStruct>();

        for (int j = 0; j < result.pointidentifier.Length; j++)
        {
            if (!pointValues.ContainsKey(result.pointidentifier[j]))
            {
                PointStruct ps = new PointStruct();
                ps.name = "Random String"; 
                ps.pointidentifier = result.pointidentifier[j];
                ps.outofservice = result.outofservice[j];

                pointValues.Add(result.pointidentifier[j], ps);
                ...
```

pointValues is stored as a private field in a class. Now in the same class but in a different function, if I try to do the following:

```
PointStruct ps = pointValues[s];
MessageBox.Show(ps.name);
MessageBox.Show(ps.pointidentifier);
MessageBox.Show(ps.outofservice);
```

The ps.pointidentifier and ps.outofservice is displayed correctly but ps.name is always returned as null no matter what I do. How can I fix this issue?

Edit: Upon request, I am adding more code to further illustrate the problem:

```
public struct PointStruct
{
    public string pointidentifier;
    public string affect;
    public string outofservice;
    public string priorityarray;
    public string pointtype;
    public string alarmstate;
    public string correctvalue;
    public string presentvalue;
    public string name;
    public string test;
}
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could show a *short but complete* program demonstrating the problem, ideally as a console app. Oh, and that looks like you've got far too many fields for a well-designed struct. Any reason you haven't made it a class?

Comment: Provide `PointStruct` structure too.

Comment: @roken I'm not calling pointValues.Add anywhere else.

Comment: @Jon Skeet I don't need any methods for the fields I am storing, so I decided to just make it a struct. I'll uh try to see if I can replicate a similar program

Comment: the code *provided* seems ok.

Comment: The code *as described* looks viable (although probably undesirable); there is no reason the reference should evaporate. Can we see exactly how `name` is implemented? I echo Jon's and roken's points, also

Comment: I suspect you've misunderstood the differences between classes and structs. It has nothing to do with whether methods are required.

Comment: You say `pointValues.Add` isn't used elsewhere; is `pointValues[key] = ...` used anywhere?

Comment: @Jon Skeet well, classes are reference type and structs are value type right? If so, then I don't see why above code would fail

Comment: @SokwhanHuh yes, but the above code *by itself* shouldn't fail *regardless* of whether it is `class` or `struct`. So: something else is going on. The fact remains, that almost certainly (well, more than "almost") shouldn't be a `struct`. That isn't helping clarity here.

Comment: @Marc Gravell lol (Bangs head against the wall) Really stupid of me, yes that was the culprit. Too bad I can't mark the answer here D:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as there is no voodoo (explicit field layouts, property indirection, etc), there is absolutely no reason why a field should wipe itself, regardless of whether it is a `class` or a `struct`.

If it was a `class`, we could perhaps put that down to a careless update somewhere else, i.e.

```
var foo = pointValues[key];
// snip 2000 lines
foo.name = newValue; // which happens to be null
```

which would of course update the same fundamental object as the one referenced by the dictionary. But **that doesn't apply** to a `struct`, since the copies are separate (unless updating directly in an array).

The only way I can see of causing that, given that you state that `pointValues.Add(...)` is only used in one place, is that you are overwriting it elsewhere via the indexer:

```
pointValues[key] = newValueWithANullName;
```

All that said, though; unless you have some very specific reasons, there is very little purpose for `PointStruct` to be a `struct`. That looks to me like it should be a `class`. It is very "fat" for a `struct`. Also; in most cases, `struct`s should be immutable.

Comment: Really quick and indepth explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It would be very surprising for a struct stored in a `Dictionary` to have any of its `string` fields change to hold anything other than the value they held when the struct was stored in the `Dictionary`.  Is your name actually a literal `"Random String"`, or are you using that literal to represent some other function?  Have you confirmed that the function in question is actually working?

Unlike some people here, I very much like mutable structs, despite the limitations in .net's support for them, because they allow the owner of a struct to control who can mutate it.  By contrast, if a reference to a mutable class object has ever been exposed to outside code, there's no telling when or by whom it might be altered.  The fact that `PointStruct` is a struct means that there's a 99.44% chance that the field contents of the struct you are retrieving from the `Dictionary` are the same as the field contents the struct had when it was stored.  Add a check to ensure that the `Name` field is non-null whenever it's stored to the `Dictionary` and you'll almost certainly find your problem.  A much better situation to be in than with a mutable class, where you'd have to inspect outside code to ensure that nothing's altering it.

**Addendum**

There is one evil thing about mutable structs, which is that if you have any struct members, other than a constructor or property setters, which mutate `this`, an attempt to use such a member in read-only contexts will generate bogus code but won't generate any compiler diagnostics.  Languages and frameworks which properly support value-type semantics require that members which mutate `this` be tagged as such, and forbid the use of such members in read-only contexts, but unfortunately .net has no such tagging.  It simply guesses that constructors and property setters will mutate the underlying struct, while getters and other methods will not.  If the `Name field is filled in with a struct method, e.g.

```
void ComputeName(void)
{
  Name = someRandomString();
}
```

I would strongly suggest that you replace it with a static method:

```
void ComputeName(ref theStruct)
{
  theStruct.Name = someRandomString();
}
```

If the former function is called on a read-only instance of `PointStruct`, the compiler will--as noted--compile without complaint but the resulting code won't work.  Attempting to pass a read-only instance of `PointStruct` to the latter, however, will cause a compiler error.

Comment: +1, I was thinking maybe name is actually assigned after the struct is copied to the dictionary.

Comment: @EricNicholson: That's possible, but having code assign everything but the name before storing the thing in the `Dictionary` and then do the name afterward would seem odd even if the data type in question were a mutable class.  Still, you raise an interesting point (see addendum).